# RSpec autotest and bundler

Tags: rspec, bundler, autotest

The RSpec documentation says that you should require "autotest/bundler" so that autotest will automtatically prepend bundle exec when you run it.  Sounds nice, but I've install autotest version 4.4.5 and it does not come with a bundler plugin.

How do I get the bundler plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require autotest first, then the bundler plugin will load fine:

```
require 'autotest'
require 'autotest/bundler'
```

Tested just now with `autotest-4.4.6`.

(And you need bundler itself to be installed also):

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: hmm.. works with 4.4.6 but no 4.4.5.  I guess 4.4.6 installs zentest but now I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802610/autotest-problem