# autotest problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, zentest

I just installed Zentest 4.4.6 which includes autotest 4.4.6 and when I run autotest I get the following error:

```
gems/ZenTest-4.6.0/lib/autotest.rb:226:in `autodiscover': undefined method `any?' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
```

huh? it's like it reverted back to ruby without rails

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know japanese, but looking at

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hkj/20110724

I learned that you can make it work by changing line 226 from:

```
# hacky_discovery = Gem::Specification.any? { |s| s.name =~ /^rspec/ }
```

to

```
# hacky_discovery = true
```

This line was last modified in this commit: https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/commit/b462a8f1dcc03528d91c77cabc15f8575d9c378c

This issue is reported here: https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/5

**UPDATE**: To solve this problem just upgrade your rubygems: `gem update --system`

**UPDATE 2**: ZenTest 4.6.1 solves this problem.

Comment: I have just edited my response. I am now using gems 1.8.5 instead of 1.6.2 and it is working fine.

Comment: Had the exact same problem; updating rubygems fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found it can be avoided by moving from rubygems 1.8.6 to 1.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I just played around with versions in the Gemfile until the problem went away.  There is some weird incompatibility between testing components.